In Darktable, how to filter for image with no tag attached?
Using Darktable.
I have triaged some images by color. Now I am tagging the images according to category. I want to find all the images with a color that I have not tagged yet.
How do I filter for images that have a color label and that do not have a tag attached?

What version of darktable are you using?

Create a collection, and filter the collection on tags. Starting with DT 3.6, the "collections" section of the user manual states:

Untagged images are grouped under the “not tagged” entry.

